# Rectangle Tool Expanding from center

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Somehow I have managed to turn on expanding the rectangle tool from the center in Adobe Photoshop CS 6.

Now when I click and drag a shape, instead of if drawing from that point down to where I navigate my mouse, it now draws from the center.

How do I turn this off? I'm sure its something really simple but I cannot find it anywehere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I managed to find the answer. If you go into the shape settings there is a tick box saying From Center. Tick this to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: this is not current information

Comment: Works for me in Adobe Photoshop CC 2015, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift key and drag the edge that you would like to transform. I found that disabling the link between width and height in two places wasn't enough...

Always experiment with combos of Ctrl, alt, and shift keys.
On a mac I'm guessing it's command key instead of Ctrl key.

Mind the date for the correct answer.
(Photoshop 2019.)